# Code coverage of Microsoft unit test in Universal Windows 10 app

Tags: windows-store-apps

I would like to do the code coverage in Universal Windows 10 app but I am not able to do using Code coverage tool which is by default integrated in the Visual Studio.

Could any one please suggest any alternate tool or method to perform the code coverage in Universal Windows 10 app.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe more about your problem? I found this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff866c7b-f560-4e04-ab2e-597cd5c52cf7/how-to-check-code-coverage-for-universal-windows-packageuwp-apps?forum=vsunittest might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had already gone through the above link. and seems that it is not possible for the universal windows apps.
Now I would like to use any other alternate tool or any method in the visual studio 2015.

Comment: Yeah, I relalized that, I think codeCover from jetbrain can help you.